# Spring Tool Suite for JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: spring-tool-suite, jboss-developer-studio

I was using eclipse from long time where I have **Spring tool suite** installed. But recently there was a need to switch my IDE to start using **JBoss Developer Studio 11.3.0.GA**.

So I was started installing the necessary plugins. One of the plugin/software that I am not able to find is Spring tool suite.
Key reason why I am looking for this plugin is I can search any text quickly in my work-space using **Quick Search** Feature (Shortcut in eclipse **Ctrl+Shift+L**). I will be widely using this search option while analyzing the code base.

*As an alternative currently I am relying on File Based Search(Ctrl+H) in my work-space. But this is little difficult to open and verify the piece of code block.*

I tried to search web with all possible keywords that can help me, but no luck. Appreciate if some one help me with the plugin link for installation in JBoss Developer studio. Thanks.

Comment: If all you are after is the quicksearch feature in STS, you can also install that separately from the rest of STS. It is available from Eclipse marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-search-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Install Eclipse Photon (4.8): https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/photon/r

Step 2. Install Red Hat Developer Studio 12.x from Eclipse Marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/red-hat-developer-studio/

Step 3. Install STS from Eclipse Marketplace: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-aka-spring-ide-and-spring-tool-suite

Alternatively, you can use the Developer Studio installer [1] then launch Red Hat Central [2] and from there select the entry for Spring IDE 3.9.4. Red Hat Central is an analogue to the Eclipse Marketplace, but for software Red Hat has curated and supports. For more, see information on [2].

[1] https://developers.redhat.com/products/devstudio/download/

[2] https://devstudio.redhat.com/12/stable/updates/#central